# How to integrate Quill editor with Angular Material impementing a custom MatFormFieldControl

Tags: angular, angular-material, quill

I'm trying to integrate Quill editor with Angular Material impementing a custom MatFormFieldControl  here: https://github.com/sermicromegas/learning-management-system/tree/master/frontend/src/app/shared/ui/quill-material

You can see a working demo here (see "description" field): https://ser-learning-management-system.herokuapp.com/course/edit/5e2089a2c4fea300172bca3e

Here is the guide to create a custom MatFormFieldControl: https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control

It kind of works but not as it should be.
For example (go to the empty form: https://ser-learning-management-system.herokuapp.com/course/create):

1. If you click on the Title field, it is still valid, click again outside the field, it becomes invalid. But if you click on Description, it immediately becomes invalid
2. In the quill-material.component.ts, method writeValue() I would avoid to do something like `this.editor.root.innerHTML = contents;` to write the initial content to the editor, but I don't know how to do this

Could somone help me to improve the quill-material.component.ts?
Feel free to checkout of fork my github code, if you want to play around with it.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 8):

If can help someone, this is the source code of the component, tested on Angular 9.
I’ve named it quill-material so you can use it like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <quill-material
      formControlName="your_control_name"
      placeholder="Type your text here..."
      required
    ></quill-material>
    <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.get('your_control_name').hasError('required')">
      Field is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

---

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  ElementRef,
  ViewChild,
  forwardRef,
  OnDestroy,
  Injector,
  DoCheck,
  HostBinding
} from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor, NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldControl } from '@angular/material';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { FocusMonitor } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import { coerceBooleanProperty } from '@angular/cdk/coercion';
import Quill from 'quill';
import { QuillDeltaToHtmlConverter } from 'quill-delta-to-html';

const SELECTOR = 'quill-material';

@Component({
  selector: SELECTOR,
  template: `<div class="quill-material-container" #container>
     <div class="editor" (click)="onTouched()" [ngStyle]="{'height': '200px'}"></div>
   </div>`,
  styles: [`img {
      position: relative;
    }`],
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => QuillMaterialComponent),
    multi: true
  },
  {
    provide: MatFormFieldControl,
    useExisting: QuillMaterialComponent
  }],
  host: {
    '[id]': 'id',
    '[attr.aria-describedby]': 'describedBy'
  }
})
export class QuillMaterialComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck, OnDestroy, ControlValueAccessor, MatFormFieldControl<any> {
  static nextId = 0;
  @HostBinding() id = `quill-material-${QuillMaterialComponent.nextId++}`;

  @ViewChild('container', { read: ElementRef, static: true }) container: ElementRef;

  stateChanges = new Subject<void>();

  quill: any = Quill;
  editor: any;
  controlType = 'quill-material';
  errorState = false;
  ngControl: any;
  touched = false;
  focused = false;

  _value: any;

  get value(): any {
    return this._value;
  }
  set value(value) {
    this._value = value;
    this.editor.setContents(this._value);
    this.onChange(value);
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }

  @Input()
  get placeholder() {
    return this._placeholder;
  }
  set placeholder(plh) {
    this._placeholder = plh;
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }
  public _placeholder: string;

  @Input()
  get required() {
    return this._required;
  }
  set required(req) {
    this._required = coerceBooleanProperty(req);
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }
  public _required = false;

  @Input()
  get disabled() {
    return this._disabled;
  }
  set disabled(disabled) {
    this._disabled = coerceBooleanProperty(disabled);
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }
  public _disabled = false;

  get empty() {
    const text = this.editor.getText().trim();
    return text ? false : true;
  }

  @HostBinding('class.floating')
  get shouldLabelFloat() {
    return this.focused || !this.empty;
  }

  @HostBinding('attr.aria-describedby') describedBy = '';
  setDescribedByIds(ids: string[]) {
    this.describedBy = ids.join(' ');
  }

  constructor(public elRef: ElementRef, public injector: Injector, public fm: FocusMonitor) {
    fm.monitor(elRef.nativeElement, true).subscribe(origin => {
      this.focused = !!origin;
      this.stateChanges.next();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // avoid Cyclic Dependency
    this.ngControl = this.injector.get(NgControl);
    if (this.ngControl != null) { this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this; }

    const editorRef = this.container.nativeElement.querySelector('.editor');
    this.editor = new Quill(editorRef, { theme: 'snow' });
    this.editor.on('text-change', () => {
      if (this.ngControl.touched) {
        this.onChange(this.getValue());
      }
    });
  }

  ngDoCheck(): void {
    if (this.ngControl) {
      this.errorState = this.ngControl.invalid && this.ngControl.touched && !this.focused;
      this.stateChanges.next();
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.stateChanges.complete();
    this.fm.stopMonitoring(this.elRef.nativeElement);
  }

  writeValue(contents: any): void {
    if (this.editor && contents) {
      const delta = this.editor.clipboard.convert(contents); // convert html to delta
      this.editor.setContents(delta);
      this._value = contents;
    }
  }

  onChange = (delta: any) => { };

  registerOnChange(fn: (v: any) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  onTouched = () => { };

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  onContainerClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (!this.focused) {
      this.editor.focus();
      this.focused = true;
      this.stateChanges.next();
    }
  }

  private getValue(): any | undefined {
    if (!this.editor) {
      return undefined;
    }

    const delta: any = this.editor.getContents();
    if (this.isEmpty(delta)) {
      return undefined;
    }

    const converter = new QuillDeltaToHtmlConverter(delta.ops, {});
    const html = converter.convert();

    return html;
  }

  private isEmpty(contents: any): boolean {
    if (contents.ops.length > 1) {
      return false;
    }

    const opsTypes: Array<string> = Object.keys(contents.ops[0]);

    if (opsTypes.length > 1) {
      return false;
    }

    if (opsTypes[0] !== 'insert') {
      return false;
    }

    if (contents.ops[0].insert !== '\n') {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer with the community. We are always reading questions and trying to find a way to provide the answer that everyone needs. Unfortunately, we can't always help. Perhaps one day it may be that someone also needs help with the same problem. I think your initiative to share knowledge with others is important. Please keep it up.

Comment: @Loa you okay bro?

Comment: if you have any errors with fast-diff/diff change @types/quill version to
@types/quill": "=1.3.10"

Comment: @Daniele Thanks for sharing this! This makes ngx-quill obsolete for me. Especially since your solution has much better integration with Angular Material.